# Promise does not return any value on state resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm stuck on return undefined value. When I `console.log` in `route.js` then it would give the response. But in my controller the result return was `undefined`. How to return the value from the `revisions` factory route? Anyone can help me?

My current code:

In my `route.js`:

```
.state('question', {
        url: '/question',
        templateUrl: 'modules/question/question.html',
        resolve:{
            revisions: function($q)
            {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                return function(module,student_id)
                {
                    console.log('revisions/'+module+'/students/'+student_id+'/questions/');
                    firebase.database().ref('revisions/'+module+'/students/'+student_id+'/questions/').once('value',function(snap){
                        var revision_qst =  snap.val();
                        return deferred.resolve(revision_qst);
                    });
                }

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        },
        controller:'questionCtrl'
    })
```

While in my controller:

```
.controller('questionCtrl',function($scope,revisions){
     console.log(revisions('module_name','student_id'));
});
```

Comment: I need to pass the argument to the factory, so I need to create a function. So how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Really not an appropriate `resolve` if it requires input from controller. Typically a resolve is used to determine whether or not to load specific state or not.

Comment: So, what should I do @charlietfl?

Comment: Just put the firebase code in a service...call that service inside controller. Also suggest looking at using angularFire to simplify

Comment: Can also use `$stateParams` in url and use that to pass in `'module_name','student_id'` and only return a promise, not a function

Comment: Can you show me using $stateParams?

Comment: Doesn't `return deferred.promise;` return a "Promise" which has a `.then` method on it? Shouldn't you be doing `revisions('module_name','student_id').then(function(data) { console.log(data) })`?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv no... the function has no `return` and `resolve` should have no controller dependencies. Flow process is all wrong

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah you can't supply parameters in the controller _after_ it tried to resolve `revisions`. Shouldn't `module` and `student_id` be in `$stateParams` then? Edit: sorry, I just read your comment saying just that :)

Comment: @Imran to use `$stateParams` it would depend on how you would structure url for state to include the relevant values needed. Not really clear enough from what is shown to know what to suggest. Take a look at router docs to see how they work

Comment: values needed only `module` and `student_id`. I do not know how to call from the controller. Is it same as `$state.go('url',{module:'module_name',student_id:123})` ?

Comment: right...but to get them in `$stateParams` your url would look something like like `url: '/question/:module/:student_id'`. Then you can `resolve` by using `$stateParams` instead of the function... Can also use `$stateParams` in controller

Comment: Thank you very much @charlietfl I loved to use `$stateParams` way.